# Retrieving private data from HTML server on a second HTML system

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking at some gadgets for automation.  They offer various analog and digital data sampling and control.  They host web pages in which one can embed comments containing private codes for controlling the device ala

```
<!-- (READ X) -->
```

The gadget replaces the comment with the value of X so by sprinkling these comments in the html, one can incorporate the data values in the html.

My question is this: Is there some way I could capture the value X in a javascript variable on a system external to the gadget?

I can add html and css scripts to the gadget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the comment nodes -- you can access them as regular DOM nodes. But watch out for browser incompatibilities.

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = "<!-- (READ X) -->";

div.childNodes[0].data;             // returns (READ X)
```

Read [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1563-jQuery-Comments-Plug-in-To-Access-HTML-Comments-For-DOM-Templating.htm) article -- it's a jQuery plugin.

Comment: The only place the comment has meaning is on the gadget; I don't want to capture the value there with javascript.  I want to capture the value in javascript on a different system within a browser.

Comment: don't understand what you're after -- explain with an example!

Comment: Ok, say system G is the gadget.  There's some set of values on G that I can incorporate into HTML using the comment business.  Now consider a completely different system U.  In a browser on U, I want to retrieve these values from G in javascript, manipulate them, and create HTML incorporating them.  Could I put those values into HTML tag attributes in a page on G, retrieve them from that page from U and access them on U?

Comment: The gadget also supposedly supports what they call HTML CGI GET POST. Could HTML on U get the results of a CGI script running on G?

Comment: Not sure what that means but maybe so.

Comment: I'm running IIS on my XP system.  Is there anything I can use to substitute values into such comments?